# What is this kind of symbol meant to be?

Tags: circuit-analysis, terminology

I found this picture in some old labnotes where one wants to determine the vacuum permittivity \$\epsilon_0\$ by using a resonance circuit for a sender and recipient each. However, I don't understand what the connecting line between \$C_d\$ and \$C_z\$ is supposed to be. Can anyone help out here?

Usually open circles are meant to be power supplies or a voltage source, as it is also depicted in the left hand side of the picture. However, this doesn't make sense here...

[image]

Comment: That schematic has a "look" that places it somewhere in the style of my ARRL handbooks from 1945 through 1953 (I only have one or two for each decade).  In particular, in my 1964 Handbook coils have gone over to having four "loops", each U-shaped without overlap, and generally look typeset rather than a facsimile of something done by a Really Good draftsman.  I'm not sure how that dates the hand that drew this, but the person probably learned their stuff before 1960.

Comment: "Usually open circles are meant to be power supplies or a voltage source" - partially correct. Open circles are _terminations_ or _connections_, which makes the meaning of the dashed lines clear.

Comment: @TimWescott - I hope you aren't implying the facsimile was done by a "Really Good draftsman".  When I was hand drafting before affordable CAD, I would have been immediately fired if I had handed in anything even remotely resembling this atrocity.  I mean, the lines aren't even straight or the angles square! While it's not bad for an amateur, I would never apply the "Really Good draftsman" label....

Comment: @Hitek not this one, no.  But the drawings in the old ARRL Handbooks were superb.

Comment: @TimWescott- Yes, I agree!  The drawings I have personally seen in the old ARRL handbooks were quite superb!  I'm pretty sure this didn't come from any ARRL handbook...

Answer (score 14):

The dashed lines between C<sub>d</sub> and C<sub>z</sub> simply denote a temporary connection between the test circuit and, e.g., an oscilloscope.

And I think the circle on the right with the squiggly line in it does in fact represent a CRO (cathode ray oscilloscope), with deflection plates and the resulting displayed waveform.

C<sub>z</sub> and C<sub>m</sub> represent the parasitic capacitances associated with the scope that will affect the measurement.